# Allow %20 in web2py requests args

Tags: web2py

I am trying to get requests to pass on encoded strings in a URL.  For example:

```
/application/controller/function/hello%20world
```

so that in my function I can access request.args and get a string that I can unquote().

I tried modifying rewrite.py to not convert %20 but that caused some error.  Something else is catching these requests somewhere that I am having trouble finding.  I noticed the httpserver.log file has:

```
127.0.0.1, 2011-09-02 00:12:09, GET, /application/controller/function/hello world, HTTP/1.1, 200, 0.169954
```

with the space already converted.  Maybe that gives a hint.  Where are the url's getting unencoded?

Below are the contents of my routes file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

default_application = 'chips'
default_controller = 'default'
default_function = 'index'


routes_onerror = [
   (r'*/404', r'/chips/static/404.html')
   ,(r'*/*',  r'/chips/static/error.html')
]
```

Comment: Are you using routes.py? If so, are you using the parameter-based system or the pattern-based system?

Comment: I am only using routes to change the default application.  I'm not sure which type of system I'm using.

Comment: What is the content of your routes.py file?

Comment: I edited the question to include the contents.

Comment: Is your app behind a web server such as lighttpd, nginx, apache, etc? They can also alter URLs.

Comment: I have my local server which is the only one I've been using for testing which is behind nothing - I run python web2py.py.  I will definitely have to keep that in mind though when these go on a live server behind apache!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, web2py will not allow special characters in args except '@', '-', '=', and '.'. To override that behavior, you can add the following to routes.py:

```
routes_apps_raw=['chips']
```

In that case, request.args will be set to `None`, and instead you can access the raw args from the URL via `request.raw_args`. Note, though, that `routes_apps_raw` does not work if you are using the [parameter-based rewrite system](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/4#Parameter-based-system) (i.e., if your routes.py file includes a `routers` dictionary).

Note, even with the above change, the Rocket web server included with web2py will still automatically `unquote()` the URL, so you'll get the special characters in `request.raw_args`, but they will already be decoded.

If you are instead using the parameter-based rewrite system, you can control which characters are allowed in URL args via the `args_match` key, which takes a regular expression as its value. The default regex is `r'([\w@ -]|(?<=[\w@ -])[.=])*$'`, which allows '@', '-', '=', and '.' (with some restrictions on '=' and '.').

Comment: Note that the list of allowed characters seems to have now changed to those that match the following regexp: r'([\w@ -]|(?<=[\w@ -])[.=])*$

Comment: No, the allowed characters have not changed - you can have "@" or "-" anywhere in the arg but "=" or "." only at the end of an arg (as long as those are not the only characters).

Comment: Yes, the chars are the same, but the allowed position is different - I can now have = or . within the arg itself, and thats what the regexp allows too. Try `re.match( r'([\w@ -]|(?<=[\w@ -])[.=])*$', 'abcd=efgh')`

Comment: Actually, it's a bit more complicated, and I have updated the answer. The regex you have shown is not the default -- it is only used if you are using the parameter-based rewrite system and do not specify a value for the `args_match` key. You are correct that it allows '=' or '.' within an arg, but it allows only one such character in a row, and they must come after one or more other characters. When not using the parameter-based rewrite, by default the args can have any number of '=' or '.' anywhere.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful.